# How to display Groups alphabetically on swagger-ui?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore** to create my swagger-ui.

I can order operations within a group the way I want, but how to order the groups themselves?

Ex: the correct order would be: ContratedDemand, Demand, Subscriptions and Users, but I'm getting as the image below.

[image]

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.2.0

UPDATE: According to @HelderSepu (tks!), I have to set the Tags and the operations will be ordered according to them.

So, how to set the tags the way I want using Swashbuckle?

Comment: The order of the groups is controlled by the tags section, If you share your swagger.json I can show you where to make the correction

Comment: @HelderSepu: Sorry, I'm not generating the swagger.json by hand, I'm using Swashbuckle for that. If tags are the answer, how to set the tags the way I want using Swashbuckle?

Comment: You can change your swagger.json using IDocumentFilters ... but without some sample code there is nothing anyone can do

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of sample code you would like me to provide. What I'm trying to achieve is to alphabetically order the operations of any swagger-ui generated page by Swashbuckle. It's not specific to my implementation, specially if an IDocumentFilter would do. I tried to find where exactly that setting would be in the Apply method and its parameters. I'm sure someone already did that. I will try again this afternoon. Tks.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, you just being mean. There is no code to post in this case. If you don't know how to answer, no problem, just let anyone else do it. Also, downvoting my question just because it took me a couple days to get back doesn't help either, it just make people sad.

Comment: Sorry but your question has no way to reproduce your very specific problem... but look into IDocumentFilter: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=IDocumentFilter

Comment: Share a link to your code on GitHub, I will fork it and make the correction for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176947/discussion-between-andrecarlucci-and-heldersepu).

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem.

The issue was due a conflict with the **"LowerCaseDocumentFilter"** (an **IDocumentFilter**) used to create all paths with lower case instead of the default .net PascalCase.

The code I was using was found here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/834

That class works fine for its purposes, but as it adds and removes the paths from the SwaggerDocument path dictionary, **it changes the groups order as a side effect**.

I removed this filter and the groups are now ordered alphabetically.